# Copy a list of files fast with access time in windows

Tags: python, windows, copy

This question has been asked in different ways allready, but I am not happy with the answers so far, that's why I'm asking this question with specific needs.

I want to copy files on windows using python 2.7 in the style

```
file a --> destination a
file b --> destination b
etc.
```

Two specific needs is doing that **fast** and preserving file access time stamps. So `shutil` is out of the picture. I feel, that launching a subprocess for each file and using `cmd` has a lot of overhead especially for a lot of small files. So, what is the fastest way of doing a timestamp-preserving batch copy?

Comment: Try to batch by destination and use subprocess to loop [robocopy.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145) over the batches using the `/MT` switch for multithreaded copying. Also try using the [win32file](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32file.html) module from PyWin32 to call `CopyFileW`, `GetFileTime`, and `SetFileTime`.

Comment: I have files at different sources to different destinations. So that means launching one subprocess per file? Seems again a lot of overhead. Or can I set lists for input and output?

Comment: cmd is of no help since its internal `copy` doesn't preserve the access time. For robocopy, I was hoping you had some redundancy in the destination directories, assuming the filename is being preserved, which allows one instance of robocopy per destination. Try the second suggestion to write a copy function using the `win32file` module to copy the file and access time.

Comment: In my case I do have redundancy in the destination directories. But I wanted to have a more general answer on how to tackle the problem, as I couldn't see a good working and easy solution that is also fast.

Comment: @eryksun: Can you show me a working minimal example in python how to batch files via destination?

Comment: Adding to first comment: CopyFileW automatically tries to keep access times consistent.

Comment: `CopyFile` preserves the last written time, not the last access time or creation time.

Comment: I don't know why, but in my case the access time is definitely preserved.

Comment: How are you checking the access time?

Comment: Windows --> Right click --> File properties. To be more exact: Creation time is not preserved. File change time and last access stay the same. And that's perfectly expected behaviour.

Comment: We're not getting a consistent result here, so you should call `GetFileTime` / `SetFileTime` (this works; tested). For me in 64-bit Windows 10, I set a breakpoint on `CopyFileW` and subsequently on the `NtSetInformationFile` system call to inspect what it's setting for the target's [`FileBasicInformation` (4)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545762). `CreationTime` and `LastAccessTime` are zero (i.e. keep the existing value) while `LastWriteTime` and `ChangeTime` are both set. This matches what I see in Explorer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114542/discussion-between-dschoni-and-eryksun).

Answer (score -1):

1) Use Python to create a 'batch file' that zips the files from the source, then unzips them at the destination.
2) Execute the batch file.

This will ensure the timestamps are the same at source and destination, and also means only one process is created to do the work.

Comment: Compression is a very time consuming process. I want only copy. Minimum overhead.

Comment: No need to compress.  Just tell zip to copy files.

Comment: Why down vote my answer?  Does it not solve the problem?

Comment: It solves the problem but doesn't answer the question.